# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes)

Tags: errors, memory, fatal-error, performance

I' fetching some information from my website e.g `category_name`, `category_id` etc. with wordpress codex and encode them with json. I'm using them in my android application, but today, suddenly, it gave Fatal error, I can't get any data now.

Error :

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 45 bytes) in C:\WT-NMP\WWW\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1565

Here are the codes (it is giving error) :

```
if(isset($_GET['ana_kategori'])){

    $rules=array(
        'parent'=>0,
    );

    $categories = get_categories($rules);

    if($categories){

        foreach($categories as $category) {
            if((($category->term_id)!=1)) {
                $postsrules = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'category' => $category->cat_ID,
                    'post_status'=> 'publish'
                    );

                foreach ( $myposts as $post ) {

                    $videoimg=get_post_meta( $post->ID);
                    if($videoimg['small_icon']!=null) {
                        $videoimg=$videoimg["small_icon"];
                        break;
                    }
                }

                $output[]=array(
                    'Category_Name'=>$category->name,
                    'Term_ID' => $category->term_id,
                    'Image' => $videoimg[0],
                    ); 
                $videoimg[0]=null;
            } // if
        } // foreach

        echo json_encode($output);

    } // first if
}
```

I changed the `memory_limit` in php.ini to `512M` but it didn't work. So I've changed again, `8096M`, still the same. I'm using the same algorithms as it. They are working great, but this is not working.

Any suggestions to what my problem might be?

Comment: I've re-indented your code, I ***strongly*** recommend you find a code editor that auto-indents

Comment: Can you also explain what your code is supposed to do when it works? Are there 5 categories? 50? 500? 50,000?

Comment: there are 120 - 150 categories.

Comment: Does it still crash if you remove processing the result and reduce code to querying part alone?